# Crontab permission not permitted after upgrade

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, cron

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 but the upgrade doesn't seem to have completed successfully. When I try to install a new package, as an example: `sudo apt install virtualenv` I get the following error:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up cron (3.0pl1-137ubuntu3) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/crontab ...
dpkg: error processing package cron (--configure):
 unable to install '/etc/crontab.dpkg-new' as '/etc/crontab': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cron
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Regardless of package this error appears. I have followed other questions and checked permissions in `/etc/cron.d`, `root` has access to all, I can even create a new `cron job` and trigger it however when it comes to installing new packages the error still persists. I have checked `systemctl` and `cron` service is active and running just fine.

```
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-15 14:56:10 UTC; 17min ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 59355 (cron)
      Tasks: 185 (limit: 18962)
     Memory: 114.7M
        CPU: 317ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
```

What could have gone wrong during the installation for this issue to occur?

---

Update:

The issue still remains however I've noticed a change after @steelworker and @jos recommendations. Now when I try to install there error is a different error:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up cron (3.0pl1-137ubuntu3) ...
chown: changing ownership of '/var/spool/cron/crontabs': 
Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package cron (--configure):
installed cron package post-installation script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

When executing `sudo ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs` this is the result:

```
total 12
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab 4096 Nov 14  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 Oct 26  2020 ..
-rw------- 1 git  crontab  250 Nov 14  2021 git
```

and one level up this is returned:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root    4096 Oct 26  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root    4096 Oct 26  2020 ..
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4096 Oct 26  2020 atjobs
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4096 Nov 12  2018 atspool
drwx-wx--T 2 root   crontab 4096 Nov 14  2021 crontabs
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142936/discussion-on-question-by-arj-crontab-permission-not-permitted-after-upgrade); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.